# How to indicate the points on a Box Plot using R

Tags: r, points, boxplot

I am using the following in R to generate a Boxplot out of a given set of data:

```
boxplot(set5, col=c(3,4), names=c("5 observation box plot"))
```

I also want to plot the specific points on the Boxplot. At present, I only have the quartile boxes generated out of points, but the actual points are not shown. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?:

```
d<-rnorm(30)
boxplot(d)
points(rep(1,length(d)),d)
```

Comment: Yes, that does the job :)